# imported Csv not utf 8 in Phpmyadmin

Tags: database, csv, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I imported a .csv file with utf-8 to my phpmyadmin.

I set the Character encoding of the file to

```
utf-8,
```

the seperator to

```
;
```

and the rest to default.

The import worked successfully, but then I switched to  the view of the "created database" and saw that all (German) Accents like:

```
Ü, Ö, Ä, ß..
```

Are replaced with

```
?
```

I guess something with the phpmyadmin unicode is wrong,

because my imported csv can show those accents.

Does anyone how a few tips or a solution?

EDIT:

I looked through the my.ini to check for the default character settings,
but they seem to be fine.

```
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
```

The Structur (next to view) in phpmyadmin also shows

utf8_general_ci

Comment: So, is the CSV file actually encoded in UTF-8? How have you confirmed that? Are your tables/columns set to store utf8?

Comment: It was converted from an .xlsx to a .csv with the option utf-8, thus it shows the accents ("Ü, Ä...")

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor and tell it explicitly to open it as UTF-8, does the data look okay? Even lower: if you open it in a hex editor, are the byte representations of the characters as they should be in UTF-8? And again, what about the tables/columns?

Comment: They look ok, the accents are fine.

Comment: And. The. Tables/Columns?!

Comment: Sorry, the tables and coloumns look fine too.

Comment: can you provide the sample csv file that you are trying to upload to investigate more.

Answer (score 1):

Importing a CSV file with special characters require the file be saved in a UTF-8 format. Please follow the steps below

1. Open the CSV file using text editor like Notepad(recommended).
2. Click File > Save As, enter a file name and change the encoding to UTF-8. Then click the Save button.

Now, import the file again and all the special characters should be properly imported.